# Bounded operator are Sectorial.

Tags: functional-analysis

Daniel Henry defines:

"We call a linear operador in a Banach space $X$ a *sectorial operator* if it is a closed densely defined operator such that, for some $\phi\in \left(0, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ and some $M\geq 1$ and real $a$, the sector
$$S_{a, \phi}=\{\lambda \mid \phi\leq|\arg(\lambda-a)|\leq \pi, \lambda\neq a\} $$
is in the resolvent set of $A$ and
$$ \|(\lambda -A)^{-1}\|\leq \dfrac{M}{|\lambda -a|}."$$

I wanto to prove a basic example: bounded operators are sectorials.

What I know until now: If $A$ is a bounded operator, then $\{\lambda ; |\lambda|>\|A\|\}\subset \rho(A)$ and $$(\lambda-A)^{-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \lambda^{-n-1}A^n.$$

So, the outside of the circle of center $(0, 0)$ and radius $\|A\|$ is in $\rho(A)$. Taking $a=-2\|A\|$ and $\phi=\pi/4$, it is easy to see that the sector $S_{a, \phi}$ is in the resolvent set of $A$.
I can note that $|\lambda|>\|A\|\sqrt 2$ for all $\lambda$ in $S_{a, \phi}$ because $S_{a, \phi}$ doesn't intersects the circle of center $(0, 0)$ and radius $\|A\|\sqrt 2$.

Then
$$(\lambda-A)^{-1}\leq \dfrac{1}{|\lambda|}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2}\right)^n<\dfrac{2}{|\lambda|}. $$

But I can't to obtain $|\lambda-a|$ in the denominator.

Anyone can help?

Comment: I don't understand. The inequality must work for every $\lambda\in S_{a, \phi}$.

Comment: You are right, I deleted my comment.

Comment: You can suppose without loss of generality that you are working with a translation of A, that is a sectorial operator too. After prove this, you can considerated this translation, so you avoid this term.